# Why do I get a parsing error on this line in a DTD

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

When trying to validate a [cXML](http://cxml.org/) file against the supplied DTD I get the error message

> The parameter entity replacement text must nest properly within markup declarations.

on this line in the DTD

```
<!ENTITY % Object.ANY '|xades:QualifyingProperties|cXMLSignedInfo|Extrinsic'>
```

I know nothing about DTDs. Is this a problem with the DTD or the .Net parser?

(I can work around the error by replacing the text with an empty string but don't understand the implications)